# unsafe code explanation

Tags: c#-4.0, bitmap, unsafe, bitmapdata

```
        private static Complex[,] FromBitmapData(BitmapData _BitmapData)
        {
            if (_BitmapData.PixelFormat != PixelFormat.Format8bppIndexed)
            {
                throw new Exception("Source can be grayscale (8bpp indexed) only.");
            }

            int width = _BitmapData.Width;
            int height = _BitmapData.Height;
            int offset = _BitmapData.Stride - width;

            if ((!Utils.IsPowerOf2(width)) || (!Utils.IsPowerOf2(height)))
            {
                throw new Exception("Image width and height should be power of 2.");
            }

            Complex[,] data = new Complex[width, height];

            unsafe
            {
                byte* src = (byte*)_BitmapData.Scan0.ToPointer();

                for (int y = 0; y < height; y++)
                {
                    for (int x = 0; x < width; x++, src++)
                    {
                        data[y, x] = new Complex((float)*src / 255, 
                                                    data[y, x].Imaginary);
                    }

                    src += offset;
                }
            }

            return data;
        }
```

Why is the value pointed by `*src` is divided by 255?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**What is `Stride`?**

For purposes like alignment, etc. sometimes row of pixels in a bitmap is longer than width - and it’s length is called stride. So, you could have width = 3 and stride = 4, and row of data would look like this:

```
Row: [Pixel][Pixel][Pixel][Unused]
```

**What does `offset` represent?**

It’s a difference between stride and width, i.e. when you have read all real pixels in a row, how much unused ones you need to skip in order to get to next row.

**Why is `src` incremented by 1 in the inner loop, and, again incremented by `offset` in the outer loop?**

Inner loop reads pixels of the row, so `src` is incremented by 1 to get to next pixel in every iteration. But after you read them all, you need to skip `offset` of unused data to get to next row.

**Why is the value pointed by `*src` is divided by `255`?**

Complex type has floating point components, and pixels in 8bpp bitmaps are represented by bytes, so they have values from `0–255`. Dividing by `255` converts them to floating point numbers in range `0.0–1.0`.

**Why is `data[x,y].Imaginary` passed as a parameter?**

For some reason, this function stores bitmap data in complex type, and complex type has real and imaginary components, so assigning

```
data[y, x] = new Complex(something, data[y,x].Imaginary);
```

means: set real component of `data[y,x]` to something and leave imaginary component as it is.